# Hide ImageMargin and CheckMargin in ToolStripDropDownMenu

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstrip

I'm trying to set the ImageMargin and CheckMargin properties in every ToolSTripDropDownMenu within a certain ToolStrip.

```
foreach (ToolStripDropDownButton tsd in toolStrip1.Items)
{
    ((ToolStripDropDownMenu)tsd.DropDown).ShowImageMargin = false;
    ((ToolStripDropDownMenu)tsd.DropDown).ShowCheckMargin = false;
}
```

An exception is thrown saying the following:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDownButton'.

The ToolStrip contains controls besides ToolStripDropDownButtons (namely ToolStripButtons and ToolStripLabels) so I can see where the error is occuring.  What I can't wrap my head around is how to modify ONLY the ToolStripDropDownButtons.  ToolStripDropDownMenu doesn't contain a CheckMargin or ImageMargin property by default unlike a standard ContextMenu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `foreach` statement doesn't perform any filtering, so when you declare the item type to be `ToolStripDropDownButton` as you have, it will attempt to cast every item in the sequence to that type. Since that's not possible for some of the items, you need to declare a less specific type and check for the instances you want:

```
foreach (ToolStripItem tsi in toolStrip1.Items)
{
    if (tsi is ToolStripDropDownButton) {
        ToolStripDropDownButton tsd = (ToolStripDropDownButton)tsi;
        ((ToolStripDropDownMenu)tsd.DropDown).ShowImageMargin = false;
        ((ToolStripDropDownMenu)tsd.DropDown).ShowCheckMargin = false;
    }
}
```